# NextJS take many time to load json file

Tags: next.js

I have a NextJS frontend page with antd library, every time loading page, it loads a json file size < 1kB, but takes more than 8s to response (image capture below)
[Request capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVguk.png)
[Timing capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWJKi.png)

I tested on local and it's slow too (of course faster than on server)
Can anyone help me to define exactly what's problem I met? Many thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.